# How to resolve iTunes crashing with m4v file and QuickTime?

Tags: windows-7, itunes, quicktime, h.264, wmv

Every time I open an m4v file, iTunes crashes. This is the error it shows:

```
  Firma con problemas:
  Nombre del evento de problema:    APPCRASH
  Nombre de la aplicación:  iTunes.exe
  Versión de la aplicación: 11.0.0.163
  Marca de tiempo de la aplicación: 50b71fed
  Nombre del módulo con errores:    QuickTime.qts
  Versión del módulo con errores:   7.73.80.64
  Marca de tiempo del módulo con errores:   50890e53
  Código de excepción:  c0000005
  Desplazamiento de excepción:  00880aba
  Versión del sistema operativo:    6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Id. de configuración regional:    2058
  Información adicional 1:  0a9e
  Información adicional 2:  0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Información adicional 3:  0a9e
  Información adicional 4:  0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

I have the newest versions of iTunes and QuickTime. I have also tried opening it in safe mode, but the problem remains.

I've analysed the video with [Gspot](http://gspot.headbands.com/) and the results are as follows:

```
Container:
qt  : Apple QuickTime (.MOV/QT)
File Type: QuickTime (.MOV)
Mime Type: video/quicktime
Recommended Display Size: 318 x 240
Created:     2012 Mar 24   13:37:11
Modified:    2012 Mar 24   15:55:08

Codec: avc1  -  Name: H.264
Status: Codec Status Undetermined
```

What can I do to resolve this crash issue?

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: @slhck Windows 7 64bits

Comment: @slhck I've isntaleld DirectX and it only works when I open iTunes in safe mode...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my iTunes after a Quicktime update. I tried everything -- even older versions of iTunes, but it crashed every time, even in safe mode. Soon as I uninstalled Quicktime it worked. There is a Quicktime incompatibility with iTunes and vice versa. Dump Quicktime if you want your iPhone to work